# How to convert several columns of a data frame into rows in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
hundredths <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=.01)

df <- data.frame( class = sample(1:40, size = 40),
                  N = sample(0:4000, size = 40, replace = T),
                  m1 = sample(hundredths, size=40, replace=T),
                  m2 = sample(hundredths, size=40, replace=T))
```

I want the columns `m1` and `m2` to become rows and the values that were in those columns to be in another column combined. So the `df` would look like this:

```
hundredths <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=.01)

df1 <- data.frame( class = sample(1:40, size = 80, replace = T),
                  N = sample(0:4000, size = 80, replace = T),
                  m = sample(c("m1","m2"), size = 80, replace = T),
                  value = sample(hundredths, size=80, replace=T))
```

I tried to use `melt` function but can not seem to make it work.